# Error: Spark HTML fragments may only be used once. Second use in

Tags: meteor

We are getting the following issue in Chrome 33 only. This primarily happens when Session variables changes trigger re-renders.

`Error: Spark HTML fragments may only be used once. Second use in <div id="header" class="span12 last"><!-label:iqf5sgT7syEtKmtbv-></div>`

I've checked, and we only use `header` as an ID once. Is there some kind of race condition happening in Chrome 33 which will be fixed by the time it hits the stable channel, or has something that was deprecated — that our app is probably using — been removed?

This happens when Handlebars tmeplates are re-rendered. We are not calling `Meteor.render` manually.

Comment: What method of rendering are you using? e.g. are you calling `Meteor.render` manually?

Comment: Expanded on question. Handlebars templates, not `Meteor.render`.